# jqGrid with a datepicker can't store data safely

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with cell editing and a datepicker. All works well, except that due to some strange event handling, there is a risk of user data loss. When a cell is selected and its date set, the text is placed back in the editable cell, but it is not transmitted back to the server unless some navigation happens, or an enter key pressed with the date set. This means if a user is simply entering data, and they don't do this additional stuff (about which there is no feedback) the edited value is held in limbo.

The obvious solution is to use an onClose on the datepicker. This gets called, but there seems to be no way to get the data written to a server. I've tried using saveCell, but this leaves the cell text editor open after the data is written, so that if the data fails to write properly, the impression will be given that all is well. I've also tried editCell, but that appears to recurse infinitely, or create some kind of looping. I've also tried faking a keydown as follows:

```
colModel :[ 
  ...  
  {name:'date', index:'date', width:100, editable: true,
   editoptions: {
   size: 10, maxlength: 10,
   dataInit: function(elem){ 
               setTimeout(function(){ 
                 $(elem).datepicker({ 
                   onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                     var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
                     e.which = 13;
                     $(elem).trigger(e);
                   }
                 ...
```

I'm still getting to grips with jquery and jqgrid, so any advice will be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should set focus before trigger the "Enter" key? Like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(elem).focus().trigger({ type: 'keypress', charCode: 13 });
},100);
```

Could you test it?

Comment: Tested it, and a few variations (i.e., using keydown rather than keypress). This did seem very plausible, but no joy alas.

Comment: @morungos: Could you describe more exactly **what** is wrong? I don't have any current demos with remote saved data and cell editing, so I can't reproduce your problem. I personally use only inline or/and form editing to save data on the server.

Comment: The problem is this: how to force data to be flushed to a server when a cell's datepicker closes. At this stage, we have a valid date, and it is complete, so it makes sense.

Comment: @morungos: Yes, and you try to simulate pressing "Enter" key. Could you try to start `$(elem).focus().trigger` in another thread: see the updated answer.

Comment: Very close, and functionally right. Never thought of using the thread hack to avoid the recursion, but it works well. Two issues: one, I ended up using

Comment: { type: 'keydown', which: 13, keyCode: 13 }

rather than 

{ type: 'keypress', charCode: 13 }

Comment: And secondly, it looks like the datepicker temporarily pops up and down again, at least for me on FF + Firebug. I'll test more. But, as I said, the data is now flushed, which is the major point.

Comment: @morungos: Probably the datepicker temporarily pops up because the datepicker parameters `showOn:'focus'` (default value). So you can try to call `.datepicker("disable")` or even `.datepicker("destroy")` before `.focus()`.

Comment: That works like a charm, and also shuts up an error I was getting but hadn't noticed before. Problem solved, many thanks

Comment: @morungos: You are welcome! The solved problem is the only ploblem which I like.